# Trying to replicate Object.observe with ES6 Proxy - is it possible to replace an object instance with a Proxy handler?

Tags: javascript

I have an object instance that is created in a function that I cannot modify. This function returns an object instance but asynchronously does actions to the instance.

```js
function makeFoo() {
  const foo = {}
  setTimeout(() => foo.bar = 'value', 1000)
  return foo
}
```

I want to be able observe any changes to this object instance, where-ever they may come from. Obviously `Object.observe` is a dead standard so it's not possible to use that.

[With proxies being the suggested replacement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Object.observe) for `Object.observe`, I thought to look there but due to the fact that you must make changes to the `Proxy` handler instance and not the original object instance, I keep falling into pitfalls trying to observe changes (such as the aforementioned case).

```js
const foo = makeFoo()

const fooProxy = new Proxy(foo, {
  set(target, key, value) {
    console.log('Intercepted')
    target[key] = value
  }
})
```

The above doesn't work because the `makeFoo` function references the original instance directly. This issue also extends to class constructors where trying to trap:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(){
    setTimeout(() => this.bar = 'value', 1000)
  }
}
```

But this can be overcome by replacing the class constructor with a function that uses `Reflect.construct`, proactively modifying who `this` is.

I had limited success patching all of the properties on the object with getters/setters, but this will miss new properties added to the object and is a challenging implementation with plenty of caveats.

I understand that `Object.observe` was withdrawn due to performance implications, but it seems we don't really have an alternative.

Comment: I'd argue that for this particular use case, setters are the more appropriate and simple solution.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is neither possible to replace all references to an object with a different object, nor to transform an ordinary object into a proxy.

There is no API<sup>1</sup> (and no plans for one) that allows observing changes to arbitrary objects that one doesn't control. You can only use proxies for objects that you own yourself. In general, there will always be objects whose behaviour you cannot observe or alter (which is a good thing, security-wise!), be it due to private properties or simple local variables e.g.

```
function makeFoo() {
  let bar;
  setTimeout(() => bar = 'value', 1000)
  return {
    get bar() { return bar; }
  };
}
```

<sub>1: Apart from running the code in a debugger, of course, where you can set breakpoints and alter execution however you want.</sub>